# Data Privacy: Should a user be allowed to change another users profile information?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, data-protection

In a SaaS platform, should users be allowed to change other users profile information (things like Name, Gender, Company they work for etc)?

What laws (US & EU) would give guidance either way?  Where can resources be found on topics like this before consulting with a lawyer?

Should active consent be granted to do so if even considered?

Comment: Changing someone else's information implies that they had access to that information, and that is definitely a breach of GDPR.

Comment: GDPR: For what *purpose* do users access and modify other user's personal data? Once you have a clear purpose, you can think about which legal basis could cover this purpose. Consent is just one legal basis among many.